# How to handle multiple connection string in .net 4.7 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

we have two databases in our project, one for primary and one for backup. Both of the databases have exactly same data. 
we have used EF designer model to get SP's from db. we call any method by just using object.spName . This is working perfectly if we have only one db. But since we have multi db system i need to make sure that insertion operation works on both db and select queries can be run from primary only and backup will be used to get records only if primary is down.

What is the best approach to get this working, or how can i specify multiple db in same connection string

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this on the application layer... You should look into database technologies like replication to perform this, or use native database backups and restore them on a schedule

Imagine an error occurs between the first and second, or someone does a manual query - your dbs will be out of sync.

Comment: Agree. we store a lot of transaction data, in case if one db is down we have a way to at least store it in another backup database, From then is there a way to scan both db, get common data and then store it in one final db. The whole point is we cant miss any record insertion, we have to store it at-least somewhere if db is down.